# how to repeat a function using different multiple input matrices

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I want to use the function "nestedness(M)" from the "bipartite" R package. It calculates an index from a matrix (M). I have an array with 1000 matrices and I want to apply this function 1000 times varying the input matrix file each time. I have tried apply family functions but the solution does not come this way. I don't know how to vary the input of a function when it is not a number but a matrix. Any aid to put me on the way would be very very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have an array that is 3x3x3 ie 3 matrices that are each 3
rows and 3 columns. The dimensions of an array are c("row", "column",
"slice"). You can use `apply` over any of these dimensions. In your
case over the 3rd dimension will calculate your function over each
matrix. Here is the example array:

```
a <- array(1:27, dim = c(3,3,3))
```

Now calculate the `max` function for each slice (dimension 3) of the array

```
apply(a, 3, max)
[1]  9 18 27
```

Comment: Many thanks!, didn't know I can use, say, max function, without "()" and I was struggled on how to vary the multiple input matrices (M) in apply(a, 3, nestedness(M)). (idiot me...)